# How to append a query string instead of replacing the current one in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, url-routing

I'm using symfony and might have something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('home/index?color=blue') ?>">Test</a>
```

However, if I already have a query string in the URL like `?height=tall` then it gets erased. How could I append it so that both can remain?

Comment: How's your route defined? Maybe a * in your route and maybe combined with `extra-parameters-as-query-string` parameter in your route will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Symfony has a dedicated way to do that, but in plain PHP code you'd do something like:

```
'home/index?' . http_build_query(array('color' => 'blue') + $_GET)
```

Comment: Inside a Symfony1 action: `'home/index?' . http_build_query(['color' => 'blue'] + $request->getGetParameters())`